# AFAmazonS3Client how to define meta-data?

Tags: objective-c, amazon-s3

Hi im using AFAmazonS3Client and im sending .mp3 file to my aws server. But its Content-Type is not "audio/mpeg" how can i change this.

```
AFAmazonS3Manager *s3Manager = [[AFAmazonS3Manager alloc] initWithAccessKeyID:@"..." secret:@"..."];
s3Manager.region = AFAmazonS3USWest1Region;
s3Manager.bucket = @"my-bucket-name";

[s3Manager postObjectWithFile:mp3FilePath
          destinationPath:@"/"
               parameters:nil
                 progress:^(NSUInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long     long totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {
                    NSLog(@"%f%% Uploaded", (totalBytesWritten / (totalBytesExpectedToWrite * 1.0f) * 100)); }success:^(id responseObject) {
                    NSLog(@"Upload Complete"); } failure:^(NSError *error) { NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
s3Manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
s3Manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"audio/mp3"];
```